# Uncaught ReferenceError: $stateProvider is not defined Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

For some reason I'm getting this error **Uncaught ReferenceError: $stateProvider is not defined** even though `angular-ui-router.js` is being loaded fine.

the error in Dev Tools

[image]

here is my `app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config([$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

      $stateProvider
        .state('main',
          { 
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/partials/main', 
            controller: 'mainCtrl'
          });
    }
]);
```

Comment: you are missing quotes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
app.config([$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
```

should read

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)`
```

As @charlietfl pointed out its missing quotes.